# How to write a select Query inside a CASE condition in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Sql Query. It does not have any compilation error but in runtime it shows
`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

```
 SELECT a.UserID FROM USERGROUPS a WHERE a.GroupID IN 
                      (CASE WHEN @group_id IS NULL THEN (select groupid from usergroups) ELSE 
                       CASE WHEN @group_id=0 THEN (select groupid from usergroups  where userid = @userid)ELSE
                      @group_id END END )
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT a.UserID 
  FROM USERGROUPS a 
  WHERE 
    (@groupid is NUll and a.GroupID IN   (select groupid from usergroups)) 
     or (@groupid = 0 and a.GroupID IN  (select groupid from usergroups  where (userid = @userid)))
      or a.GroupID IN  (@groupid)
```

Answer (score 0):

[according to the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

> [Case] evaluates a list of conditions and returns **one** of multiple possible
>   result expressions.

basically you can use a SELECT within a CASE, but it only has to return one single result and not a list (which is something that can only be evaluated at runtime, that's why your query results formally correct but fails when you launch it)

If you tell us some more about what you're trying to do, maybe I can help you rewrite your query